# Eigenvalues of quasi circulant matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, circulant-matrices

I have to find the eigenvalues of a quasi-circulant matrix. I found this answer here: [Eigenvalues and eigenvectors for a quasi-circulant matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1839740/eigenvalues-and-eigenvectors-for-a-quasi-circulant-matrix)

But I cannot understand what is $nt$ and how the guy underwent the calculation.

Thank any help!